# Inventory Array

Tags: java, arrays, file

I'm working on a program that acts as a type of book store inventory. The program reads in a list of information from a text file that looks like this:

```
1234567 31.67 0
1234444 98.50 4
1235555 27.89 2
1235566 102.39 6
1240000 75.65 4
1247761 19.95 12
1248898 155.91 0
1356114 6.95 17
1698304 45.95 3
281982X 31.90 5
```

The first number represents the ISBN number and is the type String, the second number is the price and is type double, and the final number is the number of copies in stock and is an int.

The program is supposed to read in this information, storing it into an array (more steps follow, but this is the first thing I'm having trouble with).

The code I have so far looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Store {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] books = new String[15];
        String product;
        readInventory();
    }

    public static void readInventory() {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("../instr/prog4.dat");
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(file);
        String isbn;
        double price;
        int copies; 
        String[] books = new String[14];
            while (fin.hasNext()) {
                 isbn = fin.next();
                 price = fin.nextDouble();
                 copies = fin.nextInt();
            }

    }
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to store these three different pieces of information into a single line (for each item like is depicted in the file) in a single dimensional array.

One thought I had was to created something like this,

```
String product = (isbn + price + copies);
```

And then try to add this to the array like,

```
String[] books = product;
```

But as I'm sure you can probably sport, this didn't work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm still really new to this and it's been a while since I've worked with arrays.

Comment: hello , do you get the values of  
                 isbn = fin.next();
                 price = fin.nextDouble();
                 copies = fin.nextInt(); correctly? I mean do you get the right values?

Comment: It seems as if you should have a Book class, one that can hold the ISBN number, price and inventory count. Then you could add Book objects to your array of Book, or better, your `List<Book>`.

Comment: @Niang, I was so focused on getting everything into an array I didn't even think to try to print out the individual values. As the code is written + adding the print statements for each value after the while loop, I get the correct value, but only the last line of the file is printed. So yes and no ha.

Comment: @BethTanner, yah, `Println` to check your values is a great tool for checking/debugging your code. Anyways, do you do like this  `while` `(fin.hasNext()) {isbn = fin.next(); price = fin.nextDouble();`
`copies = fin.nextInt(); System.out.println(...); // here}`

Comment: You're exactly right @HovercraftFullOfEels, that is coming later, hadn't even thought of that affecting this portion of the code. I like to kind of test each part of the code as I go, like testing to make sure the array is loaded correctly in this example, before writing the entire program only to get errors and not know exactly where I went wrong.

Comment: Beth, if that is part of the current assignment, then I'd do it now. No sense having to re-write this part of the code when you implement the Book class. Might as well write the code once.

Comment: Create your Book class, give it getters and setters, test use of it in a small test program. Test out creating a small List of Books or array of Books in a small test program, then work on the I&O part.

Comment: @Niang, thanks, that corrected the issue of only printing the last line, so it's now printing all values correctly. I always seem to get confused as to whether the print statement should go inside or outside of the loop.

Comment: Thank you @HovercraftFullOfEels, as you can tell I'm still really new to this. I'll get to work on that and update if I have any more issues.

Comment: @BethTanner Let me know if my answer has helped you at all.

Comment: @Takendarkk, it looks like it'll come in very handy, cut I'll have to create this second class before I can test it out. Thank you!

Comment: @BethTanner, Just think like you are the java compiler, you `prinln` is outside the loop, so you will only get a single value and when you are inside the loop, you can.

Comment: @BethTanner do you just allowed to store it in `String[]`?

Comment: Well, now that I re-read the directions and understand the purpose of the book class better, the array should be Book[] inventory... Our directions state that "The Store class should store an array of up to 15 books of type Book..." so the array won't be a String after all.

Comment: Now I've just gotta figure out how this class needs to be set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I'm having trouble figuring out how to store these three different pieces 
of information into a single line
```

How about using `nextLine()`

```
String[] books = new String[14];
int index = 0;

while (fin.hasNextLine()) {
    books[index] = fin.nextLine();
    index++;
}
```

From there you can pull out each String and split it around the spaces

```
String[] parts = books[0].split(" ");
```

Now you can cast each part to its respective type

```
String isbn = parts[0];
double price = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
int numberInStock = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
```

Beware this is a long way around and will cause problems if your file contains variable amounts of books. Also, to do this for all books will require some loops.